# Magento 2 websites : BLOCK access from ALL & ALLOW access only from some countries?

Tags: magento2, php, security, varnish, apache2

There are many options and many articles, but

I want **some advice for my particular setup from Pros** who have more experience than I do.

On my VPS I have tree magento websites.

All websites have the same target countries.

The idea is to block ALL and allow access only from a few countries.

What would you recommend considering my **current** setup? see pix below

- should I use **plugins** for each website?
- do something in **Varnish**?
- block using **htaccess**?
- **iptables**?
- webmin firewall setup?
- something else?

also some automation is preferred, I do not want to manually update the country ips every week
[image: my vps setup]

Answer (score 1):

## Cloudflare option

If you are using Cloudflare, this is the method I would use.

1. [Enable IP Geolocation in Cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168236-What-does-Cloudflare-IP-Geolocation-do-):

   > You can enable IP Geolocation to have Cloudflare geolocate visitors to your website and pass the country code to you in ISO 3166-1 Alpha 2 format.
   >
   > You will find the IP Geolocation option under the 'Network' section of the dashboard.
   >
   > The option for IP geolocation will be found near the bottom of the page
2. Configure Varnish to read the header & block access:

   Varnish 4:

   ```
   if (req.http.CF-IPCountry !~ "US|CA") {
       return (synth(403, "Your country is not allowed access"));
   }
   ```

   Varnish 3:

   ```
   if (req.http.CF-IPCountry !~ "US|CA") {
       error 403 "Your country is not allowed access";
   }
   ```

Comment: I pointed domains to cloudflare and was able to block countries the way you suggested (cloudflare + varnish). It works! Thanks.
The only downside is that webiste response time went from 500ms went to 1 second. Looks like cloudflare free accout has not the fastest DNS.

Comment: Question: what would be your second option to block countries beside cloudflare ? (preferefly free option but could be paid as well) Thanks